# No option to add landscape image in image set

Tags: ios, ios8, iphone-6, launch-screen

Need to use LaunchScreen with image.I added image set for LaunchScreen image to support iPad/iPhone both.Its working fine.But issue is this that there is no option to add image for landscape orientation.How to add image in imageset for landscape? Any idea? Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Landscape launch images are included in the main launchImage asset. Take a look at this launchImage asset:

[image]

[image: img]

You can see there is a space for landscape images, so you have to include them right there.

Depending on the current orientation of the device, the correct launchImage will be displayed.

Say your app supports both portrait and landscape orientations. If the user opens up the app in portrait mode, then the portrait lunchImage will be used. Instead, if the device is set on landscape mode the landscape image, taken from the launchImage asset, will be used.

Comment: Yes this is already there but i have added LaunchScreen.xib to avoid scaling in iPhone6.So to mantain the same behavior of splash screen i have added imageview in LaunchScreen with one of image set which i added in image asset.Except for iPad Landscape option its working fine.

Comment: I want to use image set not LaunchImage set.As when i set image of LaunchScreen.xib as LaunchImage it did not take any image and show black screen.

Comment: Open the Navigator, select the target and under App Icons and Launch Images choose the image set of the launchImage.

Comment: i added the image set from there but in that image set there are only Portrait support.No image option for landscape support

Comment: Or is there any way to use LaunchImage in imageview of LaunchScreen?

Comment: Check out my edited answer, I added an image. I hope it clarifies the issue.

Comment: But i know for Launch Images there is option of lanscape image too.My problem is this i created one image set (which is not launchImage) to use in LaunchScreen.xib imageview.But in that imageset there is no option for Landscape.How to support landscape image for LaunchScreen image.?

Comment: Open the Navigator, select the target and under App Icons and Launch Images choose the image set.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? i have the same issue

Comment: I also looking for solution.

Comment: I am also looking for the solution. The answer marked as correct is not the solution.